# SwiftUI cannot set value to @State property in init()

Tags: swift

I'm probably not understanding the basics and confused, but I couldn't figure out the reason of things below.
Ok, what I want to do is pass Int64 to sub view and show Toggles based on bits and set the bits back to parent view like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var bits: Int64 = 5

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                SectionView(title: "Section", withBits: $bits)
            } header: {
                Text("Toggle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SectionView: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var bits: Int64

    @State private var first: Bool
    @State private var second: Bool
    @State private var third: Bool

    init(title: String, withBits: Binding<Int64>) {
        self.title = title
        self._bits = withBits
        self.first = self.bits & 1 == 1
        self.second = self.bits & 2 == 2
        self.third = self.bits & 4 == 4
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(self.title)
            }
            HStack {
                Toggle("Toggle 1", isOn: self.$first)
                    .onChange(of: self.first) { newValue in
                        if newValue {
                            self.bits |= 1
                        }
                        else {
                            self.bits &= ~1
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Toggle("Toggle 2", isOn: self.$second)
                    .onChange(of: self.second) { newValue in
                        if newValue {
                            self.bits |= 2
                        }
                        else {
                            self.bits &= ~2
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Toggle("Toggle 3", isOn: self.$third)
                    .onChange(of: self.third) { newValue in
                        if newValue {
                            self.bits |= 4
                        }
                        else {
                            self.bits &= ~4
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: self.bits) { newValue in
            print("bits: \(bits)")
        }
    }
}
```

But it won't compile. Saying "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized" error.

So I set default values to all Bool vars like this:

```
    @State private var first: Bool = false
    @State private var second: Bool = false
    @State private var third: Bool = false
```

It compiles now but cannot overwrite them in int(), below lines are completely ignored.

```
        self.first = self.bits & 1 == 1
        self.second = self.bits & 2 == 2
        self.third = self.bits & 4 == 4
```

Moving above three lines to onAppear() worked.
But still I want to know why they won't be overwritten in init() and cleanest way.

Answer (score 7):

Ok things are clear now. To make a long story short, we can't initialize @State property in init() just doing like this:

```
@State var bla: Int = 7
init() {
    // This line won't work
    self.bla = 0
}
```

because "bla" is a just reference to storage like pointer and so setting 0 to it won't reach to real storage in init(), it will be replaced with newly allocated real property with initial value 7 instead. That's the way SwiftUI is designed.
Whole discussion is here:
https://forums.swift.org/t/assignment-to-state-var-in-init-doesnt-do-anything-but-the-compiler-gened-one-works/35235/37

So the answer what we should do here to achieve to set initial value to @State real property in init() is like this:

```
self._first = State(wrappedValue: withBits.wrappedValue & 1 == 1)
self._second = State(wrappedValue: withBits.wrappedValue & 2 == 2)
self._third = State(wrappedValue: withBits.wrappedValue & 4 == 4)
```

Above actually allocate storage and set them to @State properties.
By doing this, we can also have initial values.

Comment: Good job finding that, now I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using in your initialiser the variables being initialised, if you can. The `Binding` has no value in the beginning, that's why you need to wait for your View to appear.

Try replacing the initialisation for your 3 variables with the following code (using `init()` and not `.onAppear()`):

```
self.first = withBits.wrappedValue & 1 == 1      // Why using an always true condition? OK if this is just a placeholder
self.second = withBits.wrappedValue & 2 == 2
self.third = withBits.wrappedValue & 4 == 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But replacing to withBits fails with "Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Int64>' to expected argument type 'Int'"
I tried it before post. It didn't work either.

Comment: @J.K: yes, you're right, my apologies. I have corrected the answer, the `withBits` is a Binding and must be unwrapped with `.wrappedValue`.

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. But it still doesn't work if there's initial values. It's probably different issue or "design" of Swift though. Would you know why?

Comment: @J.K: Sorry, I do not know why it doesn't work on your side. I have used your same code and it works perfectly; if you set initial values, like `@State private var first: Bool = false`, they are overridden by the initialiser - that's what you want, correct? You can debug by temporarily creating new state variables `@State private var firstT: Int64` and assigning `self.firstT = withBits.wrappedValue` in the init(). Put that variable in a `Text(firstT.description)` in your view and try to see where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I'm just curious why they won't be overridden. I'm using latest Xcode 13.2.1. Not sure if it's a bug or design change. The wrappedValue stuff works w/o initial value so I go with it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: BTW, what's your Xcode version? I tested 13.2.1, 13.1, 12.5.1 none worked with if initial value is set. Thanks.